# MySQL check if between multiple criteria with unique identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of events.

```
| TABLE: events
| event_id | event_location | event_date |
|----------|----------------|------------|
| 10       | Denver         | 2014-02-01 | *
| 11       | Chicago        | 2014-04-01 | *
| 12       | Denver         | 2014-06-01 | 
| 13       | Seattle        | 2014-08-01 | *
| 14       | Chicago        | 2014-10-01 |
| 15       | Denver         | 2014-11-01 | *
```

I also have a list of location access, which is dated.

```
| TABLE: allowed
| allowed_location | date_begin | date_end   |
|------------------|------------|------------|
| Denver           | 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-01 |
| Chicago          | 2014-03-01 | 2014-05-01 |
| Seattle          | 2014-07-01 | 2014-09-01 |
| Denver           | 2014-10-01 | 2014-12-01 |
```

What I want to find are all of the event_id that have event_date that is between one of their respective allowed_location rows (date_begin and date_end).

The results from the first table that meet the criteria are denoted with asterisks above.

I am able to get some results, but not what I am seeking, with the following query:

```
SELECT event.event_id
FROM event
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT allowed_location,
          date_begin,
          date_end
   FROM allowed) AS allowed ON allowed.allowed_location=event.event_location
WHERE (event.event_date >= allowed.date_begin)
  AND (event.event_date <= allowed.date_end)
```

This will give me some results, but it only left joins one of the results from the allowed table. I cannot wrap my head around a way to check if the date for the event is between ANY of the allowed date ranges for that location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use an inner join for starters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `JOIN` will [return a row matching each row combination allowed by the `ON` condition](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/194f5/4). From there, you only need to filter out those with non-matching dates. (Also note the `BETWEEN` operator, it makes range-based comparison much simpler.)

```
SELECT e.event_id
FROM events e
    JOIN allowed a ON a.allowed_location = e.event_location
WHERE e.event_date BETWEEN a.date_begin AND a.date_end
```

This [returns the result you expect](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/194f5/2).

Comment: I believe its an inner join.   Outer join wouldn't restrict things the way he wants

Comment: Right, INNER JOIN. Sorry.

Comment: Awesome! I think the part I was getting confused about was the join with multiple criteria. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. The JOIN just says how you want rows to be matched together. Which (combined) rows to filter out is handled by the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct.  However, you can write it with an `inner join` rather than a `left join` and you don't need the subquery in the `from` clause.

```
SELECT e.event_id
FROM event e JOIN
     allowed a
     ON a.allowed_location = e.event_location
WHERE (e.event_date >= a.date_begin) AND (e.event_date <= a.date_end);
```